# New Web NG SDK (Using with Vue.js)

Tags: agora.io

I notice a new web SDK for web(NG). Looks good. I have looking to use it with a Vue application.

To display a video stream the function needs the ID if a Div container. e.g.

this.localVideoTrack.play("local-video")

Vue does not work this way (i.e. manipulate directly via dom elements, does anybody know how I can update a Vue component to display the video stream?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `.play()` method and passing in the `id` of the div you wish to use does work in Vue, you can check this [Agora Vue Demo App](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/OpenAgoraWeb-Vue), check Line 337 within [AgoraVideoCall.vue](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/OpenAgoraWeb-Vue/blob/73deeda0e93450c9ca281dc69004d9b8e32554ed/src/components/AgoraVideoCall.vue#L337)

```
$.streamList.map((item, index) => {
  let id = item.getId();
  let dom = document.querySelector("#ag-item-" + id);
  if (!dom) {
    dom = document.createElement("section");
    dom.setAttribute("id", "ag-item-" + id);
    dom.setAttribute("class", "ag-item");
    canvas.appendChild(dom);
    item.play("ag-item-" + id);
  }
  if (index === no - 1) {
    dom.setAttribute("style", `grid-area: span 12/span 24/13/25`);
  } else {
    dom.setAttribute(
      "style",
      `grid-area: span 3/span 4/${4 + 3 * index}/25;
    z-index:1;width:calc(100% - 20px);height:calc(100% - 20px)`
    );
  }
  item.player.resize && item.player.resize();
});
```